# Quiero saber la cantidad de objetos que he creado, ya que he utilizado UPCASTING

Tags: java

```
_lista.adicionarPersona(new Profesor($correoInstitucional, $materia,
            $paraleloProf, $nombre, $apellido, direccion))
```

Aquí he guardado un objeto llamado profesor mediante el upcasting (a la clase abstracta llamada Persona), pero al momento de yo saber la cantidad de profesores que he creado, me sale vacio, ya que está guardando dentro de la clase abstracta, mas no en la clase hija. Espero me ayuden, gracias :).

```
 public void adicionarPersona(Persona objetoPersona){
     this.listaPersonas.add(objetoPersona);             
     if(objetoPersona instanceof Estudiante){
         System.out.println("Se agrgo un nuevo estudiante");
     }else if(objetoPersona instanceof Profesor){
         System.out.print("Se agrego un nuevo profesor");
     }
     System.out.print(objetoPersona);
     contador++;
  }
```

Aqui estoy haciendo el metodo para agregar personas, ya sea estudiante o profesores con la clase abstracta.

```
public void cantidadEstudiantes(){
    System.out.print(listaEstudiantes.size());
}
```

La lista ya me cuenta como listaEstudiante, pero si creo otro estudiante, el contador se salta a 3(como si hubiera creado 2), que puedo hacer?

```
public void adicionarPersona(Persona objetoPersona){
    Persona adicionar = null;
     this.listaPersonas.add(objetoPersona); 
     
        for(Persona p: listaPersonas){
            if(p instanceof Estudiante){
                Estudiante est = (Estudiante)p;
                listaEstudiantes.add(est);
            }
        }System.out.print(objetoPersona);
     contador++;
  }
```

Comment: ¿Esto es java? Si es java ¿Por qué nombras las variables como si fuera php? De cualquier forma, por favor, adjunta las implementaciones de al menos las dos clases de las que hablas. Esa línea que pones no dice nada.

Comment: Es java, es que lo quise hacer lo mas corto y entendible posible, ya que estoy diciendo que estoy pasando los argumentos a la clase abstracta(y ahí se estan guardando) pero al momento de yo saber cuantos estudiantes o profesores he guardado, me sale vacia, ya que no está guardando nada.

Comment: Pues de tan corto no se entiende nada. ¿Cual es la clase abstracta? ¿Como estas llevando la cuenta? ¿Que es lo que esta vacio? Nadie aquí sabe el código que escribiste.

Comment: revisa de nuevo, y dime si está mejor

Comment: Vas mejorando. Ahora coloca el metodo que te da la cuenta. El que dices que te da mal.

Comment: Mira de nuevo, es ahí.

Comment: ¿No deberia decir  `this.listaPersonas.size()`? Yo veo que estas agregando las personas a una lista llamada `listaPersonas`. No se de donde sale ahora `listaEstudiantes`  ¿Ves la importancia de poner tu codigo completo? Mira lo facil que se hace un ejemplo minimo verificable https://onlinegdb.com/y3lDAG222

Comment: Es que ese el problema jajaja, quise saber si se guardaba directamente a una nueva arraylist (que le puse ese nombre listaEstudiantes) pero veo que no es así

Comment: El recorrer la listaPersonas, no me dará nada referente a una subclase no?. Es que es mucho codigo :/, por eso lo quise hacer lo mas corto posible con el problema central

Comment: Si quieres separar estudiantes y profesores, en la clase que tiene el metodo adicionarPersona crea dos listas, una de estudiantes y una de profesores. Si la persona es instancia de estudiante agregala a la lista de estudiantes. Si la persona es instancia de profesor, agregala a la lista de profesores.  Nada es mágico en programacion, y menos en java. Si no lo programas, el no lo va a hacer solo.

Comment: No tienes que poner todo tu codigo, con un fragmento que reproduzca tu problema como el que te pase en el enlace, pero debes poner lo relevante, si no, nadie va a ayudarte y tu pregunta terminará cerrada.

Comment: Pero que le paso como argumento al momento de agregar en la arraylist de estudiantes, si ya no puedo utilizar el parametro  /objetoPersona'

Comment: Antes de agregarlo a la lista haces un cast. `this.listaEstudiantes.add((Estudiante) objetoPersona)`. Esto cuando estés seguro de que es instancia de estudiante. Otra forma es agregar todos en una lista y ya luego la separacion la haces en los metodos de busqueda.

Comment: Buen dia @JaimeMenéndez men, hice casteo pero me sale un error, mira como lo hice

Comment: Normal que te salga un error, estás casteando una lista a un objeto de tipo `Estudiante`. Tú crees que una lista y un objeto tuyo son lo mismo? Pues java tampoco se lo va a creer.

Comment: Bro bro brooo, mira, ahora lo hice creando un nuevo objeto de Estudiante, dentro del for, y ya me cuenta :D